# display content of a URL in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am opening a popup window in the following format :

```
window.open('http://URL', 'invitationwindow', 'height=250,width=500,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,status=yes')
```

How I do I Get the content of the popup in a div in the same page. I mean,  I don't want the popup but the content of it should be displayed in the same page from where the popup is fired.

How can this be done using Jquery? I know `.append()` and `.html()` will add content to div, but in this case I am getting content from the URL like http://example.com .

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually people use an `<iframe>` for that.

Comment: I used a iframe but the problem i couldnot interact with content of the iframe. I basically display website survey and the user press 'yes' , 'no', or 'later'. but when I press it, nothing happens. If the content is in popup, On pressing the above button, another popup opens. Is it not possible to interact with iframes?

Answer (score 5):

Use jquery [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

```
$('#mydiv').load('http://URL');
```

Answer (score 2):

Using jquery, use this:

```
$.get('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
  alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

and

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html', function() {
  alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

Hope it helps!